# How can I generate 3D unstructured mesh on MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have been looking to do a 3D mesh for a shallow tunnel FE analysis.
The output of mesh node orientation along the element should be counter clock wise direction.
How and which material helps me best as I am a programming beginner?

Answer (score 2):

For tetrahedral elements, the easiest way, if not the only way, in MATLAB is with [DistMesh Package](http://persson.berkeley.edu/distmesh/). It is really easy to use.
I do not know the direction of orientation. However, that should be easy to fix in a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks Abhilash Reddy M I have tried but when I raise the hight just above the example provided, it get stuck

Comment: if you have a large DOF,  it will take a long time to compute the mesh. In MATLAB you can only do so much. I am curious why does the mesh have to be generated in MATLAB?  DId you consider Gmsh or Tetgen?

Comment: No I didn't check gmesh, I am familiar with Matlab and that's why I preferred it. Thanks Abhilash Reddy M.